# How can I use the same syntax sugar of Array or Dictionary in an Object in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am creating an object that mimic Dictionary and Array. I can use [subscript](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html) and can do a lot of thing.

But can I initialize my object with an empty Dictionary or Array **ONLY** with this line?

```
let myObject:mimicArray = []
let myObject2:mimicDictionary = [:]
```

What I need to do is just a common init like this

```
let myObject = mimicArray()
let myObject2 = mimicDictionary()
```

But I would like to use this syntax sugar. Can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You must implement [DictionaryLiteralConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_DictionaryLiteralConvertible_Protocol/index.html) or [ArrayLiteralConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ArrayLiteralConvertible_Protocol/index.html) protocols

[A nive article about literals](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the answer by **phimage** you need to adopt a Convertible protocol. As an example a struct that adopts ArrayLiteralConvertible.

```
struct Mimic<T> : ArrayLiteralConvertible {

    typealias Element = T

    var values : [T] = []

    init(arrayLiteral elements: Element...) {

        self.values = elements

    }
}


let mimicTest : Mimic<Int> = []
```